# QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK

Tags: python, gtk, anaconda, spyder

I have a series of apps installed in Ubuntu 18.04 using Anaconda. They run just fine, but the menus appear as blank.[image: gtk apps not displaying the menus]

Some of these apps are:

- Spyder
- Orange 3
- qtconsole

For all of them I obtain the same error when I execute them:

`QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK. Make sure you have installed the proper libraries.`

I have been trying to sort it for hours without success.

Any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a quick fix, add

`export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk2`

to your `.bashrc`. Then your menus should at least have some text again.

Comment: That sorted the problem. Do you know if this is something that will be sorted in future releases of QGtkStyle or is it something to be sorted from the linux distro?

Answer (score 3):

This is not strictly speaking a GTK theming problem. Instead, this is because your Qt version is old. You need install `qt=5.9`.
In my case, that problem was caused because I use conda-forge channel and qt is in 5.6 version there. When explicitly install `qt=5.9` from default channel the problem was solved without change `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Since I'm using Conda, I have nothing but problems with dependencies... I have lost quite a few days just trying to sort them. Now I'm in one of these stages where mostly everything works, so I better keep it as it is and try my best not to use anything new, as there's a big chance of having something failing.

Answer (score 1):

I soleved it by upgrading and installing pkg-config

```
sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install pkg-config
```

AND Jupyter series just works well!